# How do you check if the current page is the frontpage using YII?

Tags: yii

Drupal has a function called "[drupal_is_front_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/6)". Does YII have something similar to deal with navigation in this way?

Comment: why would you wanna do this? for navigation you can use the controllers 'menu' property to control the navigation links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. And while the information needed to piece this together is available, doing so is really more pain than it should be.

To begin with, the front page is defined by the [`CWebApplication::defaultController`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#defaultController-detail) property, which can be configured as [discussed](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application#application-configuration) in the definitive guide. But there's a big issue here: `defaultController` can in reality be any of the following:

1. a bare controller name, e.g. `site`
2. a module/controller pair, e.g. `module/site`
3. a controller/action pair, e.g. `site/index`
4. a module/controller/action tuple, e.g. `module/site/index`

If you have specified the `defaultController` as #4 (which is the same as #3 if your application does not include any modules) then everything is easy:

```
function is_home_page() {
    $app = Yii::app();
    return $app->controller->route == $app->defaultController;
}
```

The problem is that if `defaultController` is specified as #1 or #2 then you have to examine a lot of the runtime information to convert it to form #3 or #4 (as appropriate) so that you can then run the equality check.

Yii of course already includes code that can do this: the [`CWebApplication::createController`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#createController-detail) method, which can accept any of the valid formats for `defaultController` and resolve that to a controller/action pair (where controller is dependent on the module, if applicable). But looking at the source doesn't make you smile in anticipation.

To sum it up: you can either assume that `defaultController` will always be fully specified and get the job done with one line of code, or borrow code from `createController` to determine exactly what `defaultController` points to (and then use the one line of code to check for equality).

**I do not recommend looking into solutions based on URLs** because the whole point of routes is that different URLs can point to the same content -- if you go that way, can never be sure that you have the correct result.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using --> ... if ( (Yii::app()->controller->getId().'/'.Yii::app()->controller->getAction()->getId()) == 'site/index') { ...

Comment: And yes, I agree that understanding the purpose is important, but for a simple if ($frontpage) scenario, the above works beautifully.

Comment: @RD.: If you are not using modules, `Yii::app()->controller->route` will be the same value as the left hand side of your condition. Easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there is no such function in Yii. However, you can retrieve the followings:

- base url: `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl`
- current URL : `Yii::app()->request->requestUri.`
- current page controller with `Yii::app()->getController()->getAction()->controller->id` .

With these APIs, it should be possible to find out whether the current page is front page.

Answer (score 0):

another simple idea:

in your action (that one you use to present your 'main front page'), you could set up a variable using a script in its view:

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScript("main_screen",
   "var main_front_page = true;",CClientScript::POS_BEGIN);
```

put that code in the "main view", (the rest view pages dont have this piece of code).
so when you need to check if a page is the "main page" you could check for it using javascript, quering for:

```
if(main_front_page){..do something..}.
```

if you need to recognize the main page in php (in server side), use the method proposed by Jon.

Answer (score 0):

another solution, based on a common method for your controller:

Your controllers all of them must extend from CController, but, when you build a new fresh yii application Gii creates a base Controller on /protected/components/Controller.php so all your controllers derives from it.

So, put a main attribute on it, named:

```
<?php
class Controller extends CController {
  public $is_main_front_page;
  public function setMainFrontPage(){ $this->is_main_front_page = true; }
  public function getIsMainFrontPage(){ returns $this->is_main_front_page==true; }
}
?>
```

well, when you render your main front page action, set up this core varible to true:

```
<?php
class YoursController extends Controller {
   public function actionPrimaryPage(){
      $this->setMainFrontPage();
      $this->render('primarypage');
   }
   public function actionSecondaryPage(){
      $this->render('secondarypage');
   }
}
```

next, in any view, you could check for it:

```
<?php // views/yours/primaryview.php 
   echo "<h1>Main Page</h1>";
   echo "is primary ? ".$this->getIsMainFrontPage();  // must say: "is primary ? true"
?>

<?php // views/yours/secondaryview.php 
   echo "<h1>Secondary Page</h1>";
   echo "is primary ? ".$this->getIsMainFrontPage();  // must say: "is primary ? false"
?>
```